# What languages, libraries and other software serialize arrays with square brackets in URL parameters? ("?a[]=1&a[]=2")

Tags: php, jquery, query-string

I know that jQuery > 1.4 and since early versions of PHP serialize arrays in URL parameters like this:

```
#1: ?param[]=value1&param[]=value2  # (assuming the '[]' characters are URL-encoded)
```

There is also another way to do this:

```
#2: ?param=value1&param=value2
```

Are there any other languages, libraries, etc that serialize with method #1?

Are there any RFCs that give details about which method is valid?

What are the other ways of serializing arrays in URL parameters?

Comment: Why "PHP >= 5"? This was already working in very early version of PHP. Also your example #2 is not a "common way", but only a way to overwrite an existing variable by setting it twice…

Comment: I updated the question to be more general.

Answer (score 2):

1.) This notation holding square brackets inside the url is invalid in a strict manner. They should be encoded. However it "usually works as expected".

2.) The two notations you offer express something different. 
The first results in an array called param holding two values. 
The second creates only a scalar variable, the first value is lost (overwritten). 
Though this actually depends on the server side evaluation of the request url. I just explained the 'typical' script engine behaviour. You could of course also parse the url by hand and construct an array.

Comment: I would say it's more "naive" than "typical".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What about calling it typical AND naive ? I just describe the behaviour here, trying to avoid judgement. There are strong reasons against suddenly creating an array just because a parameter has accidentially been specified twice. In fact the more I think about it the more I think the 'typical' behaviour is more logical. The brackets notation specifies two separate values, each creating a single variable ("fast element creation in arrays"). The second notation creates the same variable twice. What does that mean ?